# No Nvidia drivers in "additional drivers"

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I have a laptop with a Nvidia RTX2070 GPU and an intel CPU but I have issues using the GPU, the driver is installed but looks irrelevant/not used. I need the gpu to launch a car driving simulator (lgsvl) but impossible to use because of the driver not working. When I use `lspci` or `lshw` the card is detected.
[image: lspci results]

I added the ppa for nvidia drivers `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j6yx.png) but only intel driver appears in the Software & Update "Additional driver" [image: additional drivers] panel.

[image: ppa]

[no additional drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVSwx.png)

I have tried installing nvidia drivers from packages (`apt-get install nvidia-driver-XXX`), it succeeds, the nvidia settings panel considers the driver installed but yet, nothing works.
Here's what the nvidia-settings says.
[image: tt]

I have tried different driver versions on both Ubuntu 20 and Ubuntu 18. The simulator works well under the Intel GPU, but can't even start with the Nvidia one, saying there is a driver/xorg problem. (The error message is not very specififc)

Is it normal that I have no driver in the Software & Update panel ? Should I use a xorg.conf file ? Is the gpu maybe too recent ? 
I am a out of solutions right now, I would be really thankful for any information about this issue or a similar one.

Edit : The result of `ubuntu-drivers devices` : [image: ubuntu-drivers devices]
Whether I installed or not any Nvidia drivers, only the Intel one appears.

Comment: What  "nothing" works? I see that the driver is installed properly. The 440 is the correct one.

Comment: Well, the simulator I am using cannot be used because it either does not dectect any driver, or doesn't know how to use it. I find it weird since it works on my other machines and even on this one with the intel gpu. That's why I found suspicous that there is no drivers in additional drivers or with "ubuntu-drivers devices". Do you have any infos on that ? I am maybe wrongly considering this as a problem.

Comment: I don't see any problem. What does `PRIME Profiles` show?

Comment: On Ubuntu 18 there is Nvidia or Intel. The software works with the Intel one, but not the Nvidia one. On ubuntu 20 I also have on-demand mode

Comment: Why you don't try `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`? It will install the recommended drivers for your GPU

Comment: What's checked under the "Ubuntu Software" tab in "Software and Updates"? The "Proprietary Drivers" should be checked off.  No need for any graphics-drivers ppa in most cases, not sure about your's specifically.  Check for any "blacklist nvidia" in all the files in /etc/modprobe.d (only nvidia blacklist should be nvidiafb, which is OK).